# Is it possible to communicate between two mobile devices peer-to-peer using 4G net (not WLAN)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tethering

I am looking for a Delphi/FireMonkey solution to communicate peer-to-peer (e.g. chat or file transfer) like App Tethering but over a mobile network like 4G. The IP and MAC addresses of all available devices are known by all (e.g. listed on an internet server).

Comment: Mobile networks don't usually allow incoming connections to devices, only outgoing connections from devices, so direct peer-to-peer is difficult to do over mobile. You might have to resort to using a centralized server to act as a proxy between devices that are connected to it.

Comment: what is Skype doing? P2P communication via firewall tunneling (Hole Punching)

Comment: I've had success using so-called Datasnap heavy weight callbacks on mobile. Give it a try.